# How to divide the material-ui drawer into header, main and Footer sections?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use material UI drawer and want to divide it into 3 sections as:

- header => #is fixed on top
- main   => #the biggest section that can be scrolled
- footer => #is fixed on bottom

so I use this pseudocode :

```
return (
        <Wrapper>
            <Drawer variant="permanent" anchor="right">                
                Header
            </Drawer>
            <Drawer variant="permanent" anchor="right">                
                Main
            </Drawer>
            <Drawer variant="permanent" anchor="right">
                Footer
            </Drawer>
        </Wrapper>
    );
```

finally, I want the drawer as below:
https://material-app.bootlab.io